# Grails cant pass Boolean to Service?

Tags: grails, service, boolean, parameter-passing

I am just starting out trying to use Services in Grails in order to Streamline my application and I want to send a Service a boolean value, from a controller, as a parameter and have it process the data and either do something or just return but I keep getting errors and I am not sure why. Below is my code:

**Controller Code:**

```
def testing(){
    def userObjects = springSecurityService.currentUser
    GroupCheckService.isEnabled(userObjects.group.notenabled)

}
```

**Service Code:**

```
class GroupCheckService {

        static transactional = true

        def useable(boolean notenabled) {

            if(notenabled == true){

                render(view:'/locked')

            }else{
                return
            }

        }
    }
```

Now the value of the "**notenabled**" item is a boolean and the code works if I have it inside the controller however I want to only have this is code written in one place so I can call it from multiple function and controllers. When I run this code above and try to load the '**testing**' view I get this error:

**Error Code:**

```
| Error 2013-09-27 22:55:21,882 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassCastException occurred when processing request: [GET] /my_app/feature/testing
com.tool.GroupCheckService cannot be cast to com.tool.GroupCheckService. Stacktrace follows:
Message: com.tool.GroupCheckService cannot be cast to com.tool.GroupCheckService
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and why I cannot pass this boolean to the service?? Thanks in advance

---

*************EDIT********************

---

I have now got the service being called correctly with the param however I had another issue with the fact that the render didn’t work, as i suspected this wouldn’t work due to the fact it is outside the controller I implemented the code changes below to fix the issue however this also didn’t work. There were no errors but when the group is locked and it goes inside the first IF the view is not rendered :S

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

class GroupCheckService {

    PageRenderer groovyPgeRenderer
    static transactional = false

    def isEnabled(boolean notenabled) {

        if(notenabled == true){

            println("INSIDE LOCKED IF")
            groovyPgeRenderer.render(view: '/locked')

        }else{
            return
        }

    }
}
```

I appreciate any help or advise that can be given on this. Thanks

Comment: did you restart app after introducing this changes? anyway, run `grails clean` and try again

Comment: Yes I have tried that but still no joy, any ideas?

Comment: Actually changing the services transactional option to false has solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: However when the group is not enabled I am getting an issue with the view being rendered, ill have to look to see if I can render a view from a service :S

Comment: your service aren't using result of `.render` method, put it into `response`. btw, seems that it's another question

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't directly render view from service, since you don't have *render*  method available in service classes.
Although, there is way around this is to pass render as a closure from controller and call it in service.

Controller code

```
class MyController
{
   def myService
   def myAction()
   {
      myService.myFun(render,true)
   }
}
```

Service Code

```
class MyService
{
   def myFun(Closure render,boolean flag)
   {
      if(flag)
        render.call view:"view1"
      else
        render.call view:"view2"
   }
}
```

Comment: from the controller I get an error saying no such property render??

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what version of grails you are using..?? Works for me on Grails 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

**Controller Code:**

```
def groupCheckService 
def testing(){
    def userObjects = springSecurityService.currentUser
    def enabled = groupCheckService.isEnabled(userObjects.group.notenabled)
    enabled? render(view:'/unlocked'): render(view:'/locked')
}
```

**Service Code:**

```
class GroupCheckService {

    Boolean isEnabled(Boolean notenabled) {
        !notenabled
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering if in your example the service is supposed to return anything as it doesn’t look like it is at the moment unless it does by default

Comment: In groovy expression evaluated at the end of the method gets returned. In this case !notenabled